# How to read a file with offset in fyne?

Tags: go, fyne

I have a large file with data. I can't store all the data in memory. How can I can read it with offset? The reader that fyne's `storage.Reader` function spits out doesn't have the Seek method.

Comment: Why not read it with something else? i.e. `os.Open(...` ?

Comment: Will it work in android and ios?

Comment: No idea, not a fyne expert, but should.

Comment: Okay, I'll try that, thanks.

Comment: Sorry, I figured to use gio for my project. Fyne has a lot of limitations...

Comment: I'd assume fyne's URI concept is too general to allow for a seek method - just think e.g. about reading from a TCP connection...